# How do I remove old kernel versions to clean up the boot menu?

Tags: grub2, kernel, cleanup

Every time I install a new Linux kernel, it gets left in the grub_config, making the boot menu longer each time.

I know I can manually search through the installed packages and remove them.

Does Ubuntu provide any easier way to clean them up or keep them from showing in the boot list?

Comment: As well as removing the old kernels, uncomment this line in `/etc/default/grub` if you want to get rid of the 'recovery' items in the menu: #GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_RECOVERY="true"

Comment: In recent releases Ubuntu hides kernels in Grub's sub menu, so it is not that obtrusive. However, it may be good idea to remove extra kernels to save space, especially, if you have a separate small /boot partition.

Comment: There is an ubuntu command called purge-old-kernels to do the job. See my [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/571360/21005) for more information.

Comment: `sudo apt-get autoremove` should do the trick on Ubuntu 14.04+

Comment: The accumulation of old kernels is a bug, with fix in progress: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1357093 . When the fix is released, older kernels will autoremove by default.

Comment: @hobs The command does not do the trick for me in Ubuntu Studio 14.04, if the kernels have not been installed automatically, but by Software Updater.

Comment: I can not find any answer that would help to remove kernels from previous release after upgrading Ubuntu to a newer release, even if a specific question about it has been marked as a duplicate of this [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/153185/21005). See also related [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bikeshed/+bug/1586303)

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels

Comment: @hobs could you transform this comment to an answer

Comment: Whoever read this should also read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653096/how-to-free-inode-usage You might encounter a situation that you need to free your inode by removing old kernel source under /usr/src/. If you have enough disk space when checking df -h but 100% inode usage. You definitely need to read the above link

Comment: I keep returning to this page... the comment by @hobs only works if your kernels were auto-installed - however you make `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge` **the answer** by following the `apt-mark` advice on [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels)

Comment: If /boot is full see https://askubuntu.com/questions/263363/how-can-i-remove-old-kernels-install-new-ones-when-boot-is-full/1158420#1158420

Comment: Useful gist - https://gist.github.com/ipbastola/2760cfc28be62a5ee10036851c654600

Answer (score 650, accepted):

## 16.04 and newer versions of Ubuntu

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

This command removes packages that were automatically installed to resolve a dependency, but are now no longer depended on. This includes old versions of `linux-headers-*` and `linux-image-*`. (It’s also smart about this process, leaving one spare version of the kernel around as a fallback!)

## 11.10 and newer versions of Ubuntu

### GRUB2 and its display of all kernels

The latest versions of *Grub2* installed in *Ubuntu* automatically display the latest kernel and hides the older kernels that you may have installed.

[image: GNU GRUB]

If you do not see your *grub* - then remember to press <kbd>Shift</kbd> whilst booting.

As you can see, only the latest kernel is displayed.

If you select the option shown (press <kbd>Enter</kbd>) then all the old kernels become visible and available to boot from.

[image: GNU GRUB Previous versions]

### How to permanently delete older kernels

First boot with the latest available kernel.

There are a number of ways to delete old kernels.  Personally, I wouldn't touch *Computer Janitor* since this is acknowledged to break your computer with its suggestions.

**synaptic**

An alternative is *Synaptic* (`sudo apt install synaptic`)

search for *linux-image*, right-click a kernel and choose complete removal and finally click the *Apply* button to delete the kernel.

[image: Synaptic Package Manager]

Repeat the search but this time for *linux-header* - you can delete the associated headers for the kernel image chosen previously.

*Synaptic* though will not attempt to verify what you are trying to remove... you could inadvertently delete your newest kernel - or even delete all of your kernels via this tool leaving you with an unbootable *Ubuntu*!.

Remember to check which kernel you are using type:

```
uname -r
```

The result would be similar to:

[image: Terminal <uname -r>]

Remember the result and the number - make sure you don't delete the corresponding image or header.

## Recommendation

My recommendation is to keep at least two or preferably three kernels including the latest.  The reason for the recommendation is that you will have at least one/two other kernels to boot with, if for what-ever reason the latest kernel you are unable to boot with or introducing a regressed capability such as broken wireless.

Comment: Removing old "linux-image*" packages using synaptic, worked well with 10.04 too. (I mention it because the title suggests it may only be for 11.10 and up)

Comment: the `-y` switch at the end of the `apt-get` line is necessary, otherwise apt-get just asks for confirmation and since the input is a pipe, it just aborts. So it should end in: `| xargs sudo apt-get purge -y`

Comment: I added another way without `xargs` so a confirmation is asked on the console before the kernels are removed

Comment: if you recommend to keep at least two kernels, you could have written your script to do exactly that ;) (I was just looking for a script that does that, but it seems that I’ll have to write it myself)

Comment: I tried the approach using Ubuntu Tweak as being the most appropriate (i.e., idiot-proof). Worked well.

Comment: Removing about 20 versions of old `linux-image` and `linux-headers` freed 4.5GB of space on my machine.

Comment: Cleaned up about 4.5GB of data doing this. +1!!

Comment: This method works well, but deletion of every kernel excessively regenerates grub.cfg, which takes time. Is there any way of disabling this for batch deletion, then regenerating it once?

Comment: You may want to keep newer kernels on your machine - you can check that   `dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d'` doesn't include any kernels newer than the kernel shown by `uname -r`

Comment: Note that the commands to delete kernels also deleted this package on my machine - `linux-libc-dev` - which is undesired behaviour. You could use `dpkg -l 'linux-image-*' ...` instead, to avoid that.

Comment: I second the question from @spacediver - this is a crazy-slow process when you have 38 unneeded kernels, since as each one is uninstalled it goes thru all the remaining ones while generating a new grub.cfg.  That is what we call an N^2 operation - it processes a kernel about (38^2 / 2) = 722 times, and is very slow.  Surely Ubuntu can come up with something better....

Comment: Simpler command for listing old images `dpkg -l 'linux-image-*' | awk '/^ii/ { print $2 }' | grep -iv $(uname -r)`.

Comment: This solution won't help anyone on a headless machine (i.e. without X running).

Comment: @Łukaszniemier your script may list a package named `linux-image$(uname -r | sed -r 's/^[0-9.]+-[^-]+//')`, which depends on latest kernel image available, so  you probably don't want to remove it.

Comment: @Dimitar, yes, the script is faulty. But changing the script the way you did prevents it from removing desired header packages.

Comment: I made a script that aims to keep given number of kernels and remove extra ones: [link](http://askubuntu.com/a/571360/21005)

Comment: @ŁukaszNiemier, you may want to see the end my [answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu/571360#571360)

Comment: any terminal recommendations?

Comment: @Lynn - it is a community wiki - anyone can edit and add more information.

Comment: @Lynn `apt-get autoremove` has been around forever, at least since 10.04. Any particular reason to mark it 16.04 and above?

Comment: @muru I saw the [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/623687/636143) mark it as 16.04+ and trusted it to do so for a reason. (Maybe in old versions it isn’t smart about kernel version removal? I don’t know. I’m just boosting the solution that worked for me on 16.04)

Comment: `autoremove` not works form me to remove the old linux images.

Comment: I tried to remove the linux image using synaptic but instead got ```dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-74-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-4.15.0-74-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.15.0-74-generic
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)``` Please help, I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 and now I am not able to download anything.

Comment: I just wanted to add that removing kernels over time left my /lib/modules folder filled with leftover data. To purge removed kernel data, this command worked: `sudo apt purge $(dpkg -l | grep '^rc  linux-image' | awk '{print $2}')`

Answer (score 428):

First, reboot your System to be sure it is using the latest kernel. Then open terminal and check your current kernel:

```
uname -r
```

DO NOT REMOVE THIS KERNEL!

Next, type the command below to view/list all installed kernels on your system.

```
dpkg --list 'linux-image-*'
```

Find all the kernels that lower than your current kernel. When you know which kernel to remove, continue below to remove it. Run the commands below to remove the kernel you selected.

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-x.x.x-x-generic
```

Finally, run the commands below to update grub2

```
sudo update-grub2
```

Reboot your system.

Comment: When doing this in 10.04 and 12.04, I found update-grub was automatically run during the purge process.

Comment: bash's **brace expansion** can be used, e.g. `sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.2.0-3{0..5}-generic` (removes 30,31,..,35)

Comment: It may seem obvious, but what this answer had that others did not is "find all kernels that [sic] lower that your current kernel." This is exactly the info I was looking for.

Comment: No need to reboot the system afterward. In fact, you should reboot the system _before_ performing these steps, to ensure you are using the latest kernel version that you probably just downloaded & installed (you did an apt-get update && apt-get upgrade before this, right??)

Comment: You may also want to uninstall the `linux-signed-image` packages that may be installed in UEFI systems: `sudo apt-get purge linux-signed-image-3.11.0-{12,14,24}-generic` which would remove 12, 14 and 24

Comment: For people for whom the above steps fail: run `df` and look at /boot`. If it is 100% full, you need to `cd /boot` and `sudo rm` some *old* kernel images. After that verify with `df` that `/boot` has some free space, and proceed with the above steps (purge also the kernels you manually deleted their images).

Comment: What does `purge` actually do? Anything beyond deleting the relevant `config-`, `initrd`, `System.map`, and `vmlinuz` files? If I have old kernels that I just want to move aside temporarily, can I just move those 4 files?

Comment: @BobbyJack, at least it updates the package management database, and updates grub (in case of kernel packages).

Comment: @devius Do you know, if there may be both regular and signed images in same system?

Comment: @jarno Yes. I don't know if that's always the case, but at least on my system both types of images are present. I guess that `signed` images won't be installed in non-EFI systems.

Comment: @devius Can you tell what does a line respective to a signed kernel look like in the output of command `ls -1v /boot/vmlinuz-*`? Does tag "signed" exist there somewhere? How does the output of `uname -r` look like, when you use a signed kernel?

Comment: @jarno I don't know if I'm using a signed kernel or not, but `uname -r` doesn't have any `signed` string on my system. I do seem to have a signed image installed and the output of that `ls` command is: `/boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-16-generic.efi.signed`.

Comment: @devius, you don't have to uninstall `linux-signed-image` packages separately. They will be purged automatically as dependencies of regular generic `linux-image` packages.

Comment: If you happen to remove the kernel of the version that's shown in _uname -r_, don't worry; just reinstall it with _sudo apt-get install linux-image-[the version shown with uname -r]-generic_. Of course, this is assuming you didn't reboot ;)

Comment: what in case when old kernel is on other ( non-boot)  drive ?

Comment: while read -r i; do sudo apt-get purge $i ; done < <(sudo dpkg --list 'linux-image*' | grep linux-image | grep -v none| grep -v $(uname -r|cut -d'-' -f1) | awk '{print $2}')

Answer (score 316):

My one-liner to remove old kernels (this also frees up disk space)

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image | awk '{ print $2 }' | sort -V | sed -n '/'`uname -r`'/q;p' | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge
```

Explanation (remember, `|` uses the output of the previous command as the input to the next)

- `dpkg --list` lists all installed packages
- `grep linux-image` looks for the installed linux images
- `awk '{ print $2 }'` just outputs the 2nd column (which is the package name)
- `sort -V` puts the items in order by version number
- `` sed -n '/'`uname -r`'/q;p' `` prints the lines before the current kernel
- `xargs sudo apt-get -y purge` purges the found kernels

Unwinding the `sed` invocation:

- `-n` tells `sed` to be quiet
- `` `uname -r` `` outputs the current installed kernel release - we include it in backticks so that the output is includes as part of the command (you might also see this as `$(uname -r)`
- `/something/q` says stop when you match 'something' (in this case, something is output of `uname -r`) - the `/` surround a regular expression
- `p` is print
- the `;` is the command separtor, so `/something/q;p` says quit when you match something, else print

altogether, `` sed -n '/'`uname -r`'/q;p' `` is print the lines until it matches with the current kernel name.

If you're paranoid (like me), you can make the last part `xargs echo sudo apt-get -y purge` so that the command to purge the old kernels is printed, then you can check that nothing unexpected is included before you run it.

---

Modified version to remove headers:

```
dpkg --list | grep 'linux-image' | awk '{ print $2 }' | sort -V | sed -n '/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\([0-9.-]*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/q;p' | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge
dpkg --list | grep 'linux-headers' | awk '{ print $2 }' | sort -V | sed -n '/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\([0-9.-]*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/q;p' | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge
```

Note: the `sed` invocation is modified. `"$(uname -r | sed "s/\([0-9.-]*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"` extracts only the version (e.g. "3.2.0-44") , without "-generic" or similar from `uname -r`

---

All-in-one version to remove images and headers (combines the two versions above):

```
echo $(dpkg --list | grep linux-image | awk '{ print $2 }' | sort -V | sed -n '/'`uname -r`'/q;p') $(dpkg --list | grep linux-headers | awk '{ print $2 }' | sort -V | sed -n '/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\([0-9.-]*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/q;p') | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge
```

Comment: Note that it is little bit dangerous to match current kernel version as regular expression like that: Dots match any character and 3.1.2-23 matches 3.1.2-2 (or is it other way around). See also my [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/571360/21005).

Comment: Here's a tuned all-in-one version: `sudo apt-get purge $(for tag in "linux-image" "linux-headers"; do dpkg-query -W -f'${Package}\n' "$tag-[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*" | sort -V | awk 'index($0,c){exit} //' c=$(uname -r | cut -d- -f1,2); done)` See also my [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/571360/21005).

Comment: @jarno that helped me to a very great extend... Kudos to your one liner

Comment: I combined this with Kees Cook's `head -n -2` to preserve the previous two images as well.

Comment: Due to unmet dependencies, I needed to use it with `dkpg -P`instead. Here is the full version: `dpkg --list | grep 'linux-headers' | awk '{ print $2 }' | sort -V | sed -n '/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\([0-9.-]*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/q;p' | xargs sudo dpkg -P`

Comment: Your last one-liner saved me from an inode exhaustion crisis! Have an upvote :)

Comment: Or just remove -y so you get a confirmation dialog on the purge step.

Comment: Yoda style cleanup. Should be the accepted answer and the answer with most points.

Comment: NO DON'T DO THIS! "That oneliner looks a little dangerous, but surely 220 upvoters can't be wrong!" I thought to myself and blindly copy-pasted. Rebooted, straight to GRUB. That command wiped all my kernels, including the one I was using. Maybe I was running a realtime kernel, can't even remember. Currently looking around my house for a USB stick to install Ubuntu Live CD on :(

Comment: Worked fine for me on old Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04 today.

Comment: Worked on Mint 18.3 like a charm

Comment: To see safely what that command will remove. You can first run it at removing the last part from the last |.
Then it will only display the list of candidates to be removed.

Answer (score 64):

### Ubuntu 16.04+:

```
$ sudo apt autoremove
...
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-57 linux-headers-4.4.0-57-generic linux-image-4.4.0-57-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-57-generic linux-tools-4.4.0-57 linux-tools-4.4.0-57-generic
```

### Ubuntu 15.10 and below:

I find this to be the easiest and quickest way. It keeps the latest kernel as well as two more:

```
sudo apt-get install bikeshed
sudo purge-old-kernels
```

To change the number of additional kernels that are kept:

```
sudo purge-old-kernels --keep 3
```

Comment: That command is a shell script, location of which you can find by `which purge-old-kernels`.

Comment: Glad they made this a lot easier in 16.04! Hope this answer keeps making its way up...

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04 I have `purge-old-kernels` without bikeshed (_random useful tools that do not yet have a permanent home_) package or any particular one.Avoid using `apt-get -y` option, is like closing eyes and hoping everything's going to be alright. Also [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/620281/349837) it is how _autoremove_ decides how many old kernels to keep.

Comment: In 16.04 purge-old-kernels is provided by the byobu package (hint: `apt-file search purge-old-kernels`). Agreed on `apt-get -y`, I'll remove it.

Comment: in Ubuntu 15,10 and older, you can use `sudo apt-get autoremove` as well. Same behavior as `sudo apt autoremove` which you mentioned
`

Comment: @Dan since I don't use non-LTS versions I wasn't sure exactly when it started. But I can say for sure that `sudo apt-get autoremove` doesn't remove kernels in 14.04. Feel free to update the answer with the specific version if you know what it is!

Comment: I tried `purge-old-kernels` on Ubuntu 14.04 and it got stuck in a infinite loop that circled around  `Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 3.19.0-68-generic cannot be found.`  I terminated it after 50+ loops and ran `sudo update-grub` manually …    Fingers crossed  I still have a bootable system.

Comment: Turns out I do still have a bootable system, and `purge-old-kernels` did remove some 15 GB of disk space.  Here's the full sequence of commands I used to recover after killing `purge-old-kernels`:  `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock`, `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, `sudo update-grub`.

Answer (score 44):

Removing Entries from Grub 2
Entries should be removed by editing or removing files in the /etc/grub.d folder. The /boot/grub/grub.cfg file is read-only and should not normally require editing.

**Too Many Kernels?**

- If you are not sure of the kernel you are currently using, in a terminal type **uname -r**.
- Kernels removed via APT (Synaptic, "apt-get remove", etc.) will automatically update grub.cfg and no user action is required.
- A great tool for removing kernels (and menu entries) is Ubuntu-Tweak, a safe and easy-to-use GUI app.
- Install ubuntu tweak
- Ubuntu-Tweak will be available under Applications > System Tools.

**Remove Older Kernel Entries**

- Select "Package Cleaner" on the left and "Clean Kernel" from the right panel.
- Press the "Unlock" button at the lower right, enter your password.
- Select from the displayed list the kernel images and headers you wish to remove. The kernel in use is not listed.
- Press the "Cleanup" button at the lower right to remove the selected kernel images and headers.

**Remove Operating Systems from the Grub menu**

- Other Operating Systems which have been removed from the computer will also be removed from the menu once "update-grub" is run as root.
- Menu items are placed on the Grub2 menu by scripts. If you don't want other Operating Systems to be entered in the menu, disable /etc/grub.d/30_osprober
- Run this command to stop the script from running
  `sudo chmod -x /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober`
- DISABLE_30_OS-PROBER='true' in /etc/default/grub

**Remove Memtest86+ from the Grub Menu**
`sudo chmod -x /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+`

- Run the update-grub command to allow the changes to be incorporated in grub.cfg

**[Source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1195275)**

**Note:**
After kernel updates a new entry is added to the GRUB menu.You can remove the older one if you want.However, most experienced users will advise you to keep at least one spare entry in case something goes wrong with an upgrade and you need to boot an older kernel version for troubleshooting purposes.

**Alternate way to remove Kernel entries (prior to 10.04)**

*for GRUB not GRUB2*

## [startupmanager](http://packages.ubuntu.com/startupmanager) [image: Install startupmanager]

You can find it under System>>Administration>>
[image]
[image]
You see in the second screenshot you can select how many kernels to show? I generally just keep it on 1, but when I get a kernel upgrade I always change it to 2 before restarting so I can select the older kernel if the new kernel has problems with my hardware. Once I know the new kernel is working well I change it back to 1.

Comment: Actually, startupmanager dint give me a window like this on Ubuntu 10.04, instead it just gave a window with two tabs -> Boot options and Advanced.. and in advanced it dint have the option to limit the number of kernels. So please update the answer for Ubuntu 10.04.(And thats why i down-voted this..)

Comment: any idea how "number of kernels to keep" can be defined on a machine that has no GUI installed (server)?

Comment: startupmanager is outdated. 
See **grup-customizer**

Answer (score 41):

Purely commandline, this will remove all but the current and second most current (via the "-2" in the head command below):

```
OLD=$(ls -tr /boot/vmlinuz-* | head -n -2 | cut -d- -f2- |
    awk '{print "linux-image-" $0 " linux-headers-" $0}' )
if [ -n "$OLD" ]; then
    apt-get -qy remove --purge $OLD
fi
apt-get -qy autoremove --purge
```

Comment: one-liner from [there](http://tuxtweaks.com/2010/10/remove-old-kernels-in-ubuntu-with-one-command/): ```dpkg -l linux-* | awk '/^ii/{ print $2}' | grep -v -e `uname -r | cut -f1,2 -d"-"` | grep -e [0-9] | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge```

Comment: @DmitryPaskal, You should add this as a new answer.

Comment: @DmitryPaskal As always, don't just copy-paste these without understanding them. On my machine this one-liner also matches `linux-libc-dev:amd64` which shouldn't be removed.

Comment: @Kees Cook, shouldn't the awk argument only be surrounded by single-quotes?  If your intent is to prepend "linux-image-" to the piped lines, this only seems to work if you use `awk '{print "linux-image-" $0}'`.

Comment: this does not work for me, it includes my custom installed kernel (Ubuntu 14.04 with 3.17)

Comment: @axlroden How could it know which kernel is custom installed?

Comment: @axlroden Try using option -v instead of -t for command ls.

Comment: @Mark Now this is similar solution to purge-old-kernels (available in Universe repository; Kees Cook is marked as one of its authors), except that this might remove the current kernel (shown by uname -r), too, if there exist two newer kernels!

Comment: does the last line (with `autoremove`) take care of the `linux-image-extras` files? can anyone please modify it so that we can also manually pick a few kernels that are not at the top of the list?

Comment: @nyxee https://www.bountysource.com/issues/38892663-feature-request-basic-interactive-purging

Comment: @nyxee or even https://www.bountysource.com/issues/38300038-feature-request-the-command-should-work-like-this

Answer (score 40):

Update: `purge-old-kernels` is [deprecated](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/byobu/+bug/1686138) nowadays.

I made a script to purge kernels even in tricky conditions. It is called `linux-purge` and you can find it [here](https://launchpad.net/linux-purge).

If you just want to purge the kernels (and the related packages) that are older than the currently used kernel, when system is not broken, you could use [this script](https://askubuntu.com/a/620515/21005).

There is also an Ubuntu documentation page that I have contributed to  concerning removing old kernels [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels).

Comment: Looks like `purge-old-kernels` isn't in the precise version (1.22) of bikeshed. Is there a reasonable/safe way to get a more recent bikeshed for precise? Or would it be simpler/safer to just install the script? I'd prefer to use a repo though, despite the long list of dependencies..

Comment: @drevicko See [here](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-bikeshed-1-52-on-ubuntu-14-10-ubuntu-14-04-ubuntu-12-04-and-derivative-systems/).

Comment: One more slightly tangential question: short of going to the source, is there a way to determine which commands become available when you install bikeshed?

Comment: @drevicko, sure, `dlocate -lsbin bikeshed`

Comment: @drevicko, see also [another question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122524/list-all-commands-of-a-specific-debian-package)

Comment: @jarno Is there a difference in function between these two versions of your script?
`sudo apt-get purge $(for tag in "linux-image" "linux-headers"; do dpkg-query -W -f'${Package}\n' "$tag-[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*" | sort -V | awk 'index($0,c){exit} //' c=$(uname -r | cut -d- -f1,2); done)` (2015)

`sudo apt-get purge $(dpkg-query -W -f'${Package}\n' 'linux-*' | sed -nr 's/.*-([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){2}-[^-]+).*/\1 &/p' | sort -k 1,1V | awk '($1==c){exit} {print $2}' c=$(uname -r | cut -f1,2 -d-))` (newer?)

Comment: @ChrisW yes there is. I just made a tiny improvement to the script, so it is best to use the latest version.

Answer (score 30):

You can follow the **Using the "unattended-upgrades" package section** of [Automatic Security Updates](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates#Using_the_.22unattended-upgrades.22_package) article on Ubuntu Wiki to perform this.

You need to change the following line in **/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades** file;

```
//Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Dependencies "false";
```

with

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Dependencies "true";
```

to automatically remove old packages, including kernels.

Also remove or comment the line

```
"^linux-image.*";
```

in the "NeverAutoRemove" section of the file **/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove.**

Comment: I did this but it was still collecting 3+ old kernels consuming 100's of MBs.  So I added `apt-get autoremove` to my daily cron job that actually does the upgrades, since it doesn't always go through built-in update-manager.

Comment: I think this works in Trusty only for the kernels that have been installed automatically.

Comment: This is great to prevent buildup of old kernels when auto-upgrading packages, e.g. with unattended-upgrades. However if you don't reboot, you might find that the package for the *currently running kernel* has been uninstalled! One issue this can cause: new devices which you plug in might not work, because the module for them cannot be hot-loaded, because it is no longer on your disk. (A quick fix for this is just to install the kernel package again, and then unplug and replug the device.)

Comment: I created [an automated solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/917306/133393) to the aforementioned issue. If you think this is a good approach, then feel free to add it to Qwerty's answer.

Answer (score 28):

To figure out what kernels and headers are installed use

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-image

dpkg -l | grep linux-headers
```

You can then remove them one by one or together, just make sure to keep the most recent.

There are also some handy commands and scripts to automate the removal.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1658648

The following claims to remove all unused kernels and headers:

```
dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d'|grep -E "(image|headers|modules)" | grep -v hwe | xargs sudo apt-get purge
```

(use `apt-get -y` to remove without question)

Here is what happens when run on 18.04.1:

```
~$ dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]

\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d'|grep -E "(image|headers|modules)" | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-headers-4.15.0-33* linux-headers-4.15.0-33-generic* linux-headers-4.15.0-34* linux-headers-4.15.0-34-generic* linux-image-4.15.0-33-generic* linux-image-4.15.0-34-generic*
  linux-modules-4.15.0-33-generic* linux-modules-4.15.0-34-generic* linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-33-generic* linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-34-generic*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 10 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
After this operation, 671 MB disk space will be freed.
(Reading database ... 227403 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-headers-4.15.0-33-generic (4.15.0-33.36) ...
Removing linux-headers-4.15.0-33 (4.15.0-33.36) ...
Removing linux-headers-4.15.0-34-generic (4.15.0-34.37) ...
Removing linux-headers-4.15.0-34 (4.15.0-34.37) ...
Removing linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-33-generic (4.15.0-33.36) ...
Removing linux-image-4.15.0-33-generic (4.15.0-33.36) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-33-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-36-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-36-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-34-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-34-generic
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
Removing linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-34-generic (4.15.0-34.37) ...
Removing linux-image-4.15.0-34-generic (4.15.0-34.37) ...
I: /vmlinuz.old is now a symlink to boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-36-generic
I: /initrd.img.old is now a symlink to boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-36-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-34-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-36-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-36-generic
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
Removing linux-modules-4.15.0-33-generic (4.15.0-33.36) ...
Removing linux-modules-4.15.0-34-generic (4.15.0-34.37) ...
(Reading database ... 156180 files and directories currently installed.)
Purging configuration files for linux-image-4.15.0-34-generic (4.15.0-34.37) ...
Purging configuration files for linux-modules-4.15.0-33-generic (4.15.0-33.36) ...
dpkg: warning: while removing linux-modules-4.15.0-33-generic, directory '/lib/modules/4.15.0-33-generic' not empty so not removed
Purging configuration files for linux-modules-4.15.0-34-generic (4.15.0-34.37) ...
Purging configuration files for linux-image-4.15.0-33-generic (4.15.0-33.36) ...
Purging configuration files for linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-34-generic (4.15.0-34.37) ...
Purging configuration files for linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-33-generic (4.15.0-33.36) ...
~$ uname -r
4.15.0-36-generic
```

Comment: The script you found in the forum is faulty. It might not remove some desired header package (if you happen to use some old -pae kernel), and on the other hand, it might remove some package(s) you want to keep.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The script may be not perfect, however, I've been using it for years, mainly on 12.04 and 14.04, 32 and 64 bits, and have not had any problems. ...and yes, `linux-libc-dev` is installed.

Comment: I suppose the version number of `linux-libc-dev`matches the version number of current ḱernel then. Here `dpkg -l linux-libc-dev |  sed '/^ii/!d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d'` prints linux-libc-dev:amd64

Comment: I still can't reproduce your findings, however, to be on the safe side, I've modified the command by adding an additional filter - `grep -E "(image|headers)"`.

Comment: Then the script may leave extra packages installed. I think you can see different types of possible packages by running `apt-cache search --names-only "^linux-.*" | cut -d' ' -f1 | grep -E -e linux-.*-[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){2}-[^-]+`

Comment: A way to do what the original script supposedly aims to do is this: `sudo apt-get purge $(dpkg -l 'linux-*' | tail -n +6 | awk -v c="$(uname -r | cut -d- -f1,2)" 'match($2,"[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+-[^-]+") && substr($2,RSTART,RLENGTH)!=c {print $2}')` or simpler way by using dpkg-query: `sudo apt-get purge $(dpkg-query -W 'linux-*' | awk -v c="$(uname -r | cut -d- -f1,2)" 'match($1,"[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+-[^-]+") && substr($1,RSTART,RLENGTH)!=c {print $1}')`

Comment: First try with-out the `-y` flag with purge please..!

Answer (score 28):

The fastest/simpler way (Applicable at least since 12.04) possible that already comes with Ubuntu is `apt-get`. Do the following if you wish to remove all older kernel versions that are not in use (Except the previous one that you are no using. This is to make sure that if the current kernel version fails in some way, you have a way to go back to a previous state). Do the following:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

This will eliminate any old files (Including kernel versions) you may have. Note that if you have many old versions, it will take a while since it has to make sure that removing the kernel version has no issues. For me, removing the last 12 kernel versions took about 2 minutes. You can also do the following:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

Which will eliminate everything downloaded and stored in the cache folder of apt. Lastly you have:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

which would check for any unused packages and remove them if necessary. This is great for those libraries and dependency packages that are no longer needed byt any app installed.

Comment: I suppose this has changed in newer releases as in 14.04 this merely cleans package cache and does not affect to installed packages or grub.

Comment: I can confirm that `sudo apt-get autoremove` does remove old (more than one version ago) kernels in  14.04.  You may have to run it before and after upgrading your kernel.

When I ran before upgrading, it only removed the old kernel's generic version.  Then, after upgrading my kernel, it removed the old kernel's lowlatency version, as well.

Comment: I meant the `sudo apt-get autoclean` command. @tekNorah I installed a couple of older kernels and thereafter ran `sudo apt-get autoremove` in Ubuntu Studio 14.04. It did not remove any kernels. I have only lowlatency kernels installed. Why do you have both -generic and -lowlatency kernels installed?

Comment: Yes, this worked beautifully for me, cleaned up all old kernels properly, and does not rely on crazy one-line scripts! Recommended, wish I could upvote this more than once!

Comment: If I remember correctly, older releases of Ubuntu flavors did not remove kernels by `apt-get autoremove`, at least by default. I think this thread would be very different, if they did. Do you have more accurate information about when this was changed? BTW. `apt-mark showmanual | grep -E linux-.+-[0-9.]+-.+` still tells kernel packages are manually installed.

Comment: @jarno you are correct, it did not do it automatically. Right now I only have one kernel but when they start to accumulate I will update the post. Feel free to update this if you do get a recent example to use.

Comment: @tekNorah, also `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove` does not remove old kernels in Mythbuntu 14.04, but in Xubuntu 15.10 it seems to do that.

Comment: @tekNorah, well, it does remove old kernels installed (automatically) after setting up automatic install of security updates in 14.04. See [Bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1492709).

Comment: @JeffAtwood  well, it might remove more kernels  that is safe. See [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1440608)

Answer (score 26):

## 10.04 GUI Method

Computer Janitor can clean up old kernels and I believe is installed by default in Ubuntu (but not Kubuntu).

GRUB 1, if you're using that, has an option in `/boot/grub/menu.lst` to specify how many kernels it should show at a maximum.  GRUB 2, as far as I can tell, does not.

Comment: **Computer Janitor should not be used** - it is buggy and has now been dropped as a default application in natty/oneiric/precise.

Comment: Rather, install "Ubuntu Tweak" as described in another answer (its own ppa), which has its own "computer janitor" (not to be confused with the "computer janitor" that temporarily was available in older ubuntu versions)

Answer (score 17):

In order to remove older Linux image kernels, first boot in the kernel you want to keep.

You can also check the kernel version using command `uname -r` so that you don't remove the wrong one by mistake.

Now go to synaptic package manager and search for `linux-image` and remove the older versions except the one shown by upper command. Generally I prefer to go with the latest one.

Now when you restart you'll see a more clean grub menu.

Comment: This is probably the most basic method that will for users who have installs w/o Computer Janitor.

Comment: From Ubuntu 11.04 the grub menu only shows the current kernel by default, older kernels are hidden in the 'Previous kernels' menu.  This method will still work for cleaning out the older ones.

Answer (score 15):

You could install [ubuntu-tweak](http://launchpad.net/ubuntu-tweak/0.5.x/0.5.10/+download/ubuntu-tweak_0.5.10-1_all.deb) and then Go to Applications -> System tool -> ubuntu tweak and

[image] click package cleaner and clean kernels. it does not show the currently used kernel so you will always be safe.

Answer (score 9):

Personally, I like using `Synaptic`. It makes me feel more secure about what's going on. The only app I've used that has an option to remove old kernels is [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/).

How to  remove the kernels you are not using:

- Open UbuntuTweak
- Click on 'Package Cleaner' under 'Applications' in the left-hand pane
- On the right side of the 'cleaning view' press 'Clean Kernels'
- Select all kernels - I think the one in use is not listed but just in case check running `uname -a` in a terminal

Comment: In Synaptic you can filter on 'Components' -> 'Kernel and modules', which include all the kernels. And sort by the first column: 'S' (Status), so you get all the installed kernels on-top.

Indeed `update-grub` is advised.

Answer (score 7):

You can uninstall the old kernels (`linux-image-...` packages) using Synaptic, and that will remove them from the boot menu. Take care not to remove the running kernel (you can check its version with `uname -r`).

Bear in mind that having a one or two older versions can help you troubleshoot, should something go wrong.

Alternatively, you can edit/remove the entries manually (`gksu gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg`), but they will be re-generated when you update to a newer kernel.
If you are thinking about removing `recovery mode` options - don't. They can come in handy if you break something which prevents you from booting.

---

Refer to [this page.](https://serverfault.com/questions/101238/how-to-clean-up-ubuntu-grub-boot-menu-after-upgrades)

Comment: Grub2 now builds it's grub entry everytime a new kernel is installed. with `update-grub` which will re-write all those kernels.

Answer (score 5):

This is a pure command line solution.

First generate a list of all installed kernel versions except the currently running kernel:

```
dpkg-query -W -f='${Package}\n' |
  grep -f <(ls -1 /boot/vmlinuz* | cut -d- -f2,3 |
    grep -v $(uname -r | cut -d- -f1,2))
```

Alternatively generate a list of all installed kernel versions except the last two:

```
dpkg-query -W -f='${Package}\n' |
  grep -f <(ls -1 /boot/vmlinuz* | cut -d- -f2,3 |
    sort -V | head -n -2)
```

Examine the list. Make sure the the kernel versions you want to keep are not part of the list. Use the command `uname -r` to see the version of the currently running kernel.

If you are happy with the results you can use `apt-get` to remove the packages.

First a dry run (using the first generator as example):

```
sudo apt-get --dry-run purge $(
  dpkg-query -W -f='${Package}\n' |
    grep -f <(ls -1 /boot/vmlinuz* | cut -d- -f2,3 |
      grep -v $(uname -r | cut -d- -f1,2)))
```

Then a real run:

```
sudo apt-get purge $(
  dpkg-query -W -f='${Package}\n' |
    grep -f <(ls -1 /boot/vmlinuz* | cut -d- -f2,3 |
      grep -v $(uname -r | cut -d- -f1,2)))
```

If you want to automate the process then add the `--yes` parameter:

```
sudo apt-get --yes purge $(
  ...)
```

Comment: @jarno I appreciate your effort to combine and optimize my command line. I removed your command line because I prefer readability and simplicity. I deliberately tailored my command for readability and simplicity. At least readable and simple for my brain. Please post your command line as a comment or in your own answer.

Comment: This combines two objectives: Keep last two kernels and keep kernels newer than the current one `sudo apt-get purge -- $(ls -1U /boot/vmlinuz* | cut -d- -f2,3 | sort -uV |
head -n -2 | awk -v c=$(uname -r | cut -d- -f1,2) '($0==c){exit} //' |
sed -r -e 's/\./\\./g' -e 's/.*/-&($|-)/')`. There is no need for `dpkg-query` since `apt-get`can handle regular expressions. Please note how I escape dots, and add prefix and suffix in the regular expression. Using the script in [my own answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/571360/21005) you can also keep some kernels that are older than the current one.

Answer (score 5):

The advantage of this answer is native Ubuntu Bash is used without installing third-party applications. Users of custom kernels who didn't use `apt` or `dpkg` can change this bash script to suit their needs.
This answer is based on ([How to selectively purge old kernels all at once](https://askubuntu.com/questions/892076/how-to-selectively-purge-old-kernels-all-at-once/892077#892077)).

## Zenity based solution

Zenity provides a nice GUI interface to the terminal to process a list and select items with **radio-buttons**:

[image: rm-kernels 1]

As the title indicates the current kernel you booted with cannot be removed and isn't included in the list. The size reported is how much will be saved in `/boot` directory. More is saved on your disk because kernel binaries reside in other areas too. **July 27, 2017 note:** The directories `/usr/src/*kernel_version*` and `/lib/modules/*kernel_version*` are now included as well.

The **Modified Date** is discovered using the `stat` command. On my system that date is *"touched"* every time the kernel is booted using this ([How do you find out when a specific kernel version was last booted?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/841810/how-do-you-find-out-when-a-specific-kernel-version-was-last-booted)) **cron** reboot script. However, on your system the date will be the kernel release date, not the last time you booted it.

## `apt-get purge` gives you chance to abort

You are given a final opportunity to view everything that will be purged and see the total disk space (somewhat misleading) that will be recovered:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-headers-4.7.1-040701* linux-headers-4.7.1-040701-generic*
  linux-headers-4.7.2-040702* linux-headers-4.7.2-040702-generic*
  linux-headers-4.7.3-040703* linux-headers-4.7.3-040703-generic*
  linux-headers-4.8.1-040801* linux-headers-4.8.1-040801-generic*
  linux-headers-4.8.10-040810* linux-headers-4.8.10-040810-generic*
  linux-headers-4.8.11-040811* linux-headers-4.8.11-040811-generic*
  linux-headers-4.8.4-040804* linux-headers-4.8.4-040804-generic*
  linux-headers-4.8.5-040805* linux-headers-4.8.5-040805-generic*
  linux-image-4.7.1-040701-generic* linux-image-4.7.2-040702-generic*
  linux-image-4.7.3-040703-generic* linux-image-4.8.1-040801-generic*
  linux-image-4.8.10-040810-generic* linux-image-4.8.11-040811-generic*
  linux-image-4.8.4-040804-generic* linux-image-4.8.5-040805-generic*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 24 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
After this operation, 2,330 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

## The Code

Copy this code to an executable file named `rm-kernels` in `/usr/local/bin`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# NAME: rm-kernels
# PATH: /usr/local/bin
# DESC: Provide zenity item list of kernels to remove

# DATE: Mar 10, 2017. Modified Jul 28, 2017.

# NOTE: Will not delete current kernel.

#       With 10 kernels on an SSD, empty cache from sudo prompt (#) using:
#       # free && sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches && free
#       First time for `du` 34 seconds.
#       Second time for `du` 1 second.

# PARM: If any parm 1 passed use REAL kernel size, else use estimated size.
#       By default `du` is not used and estimated size is displayed.

# Must be running as sudo
if [[ $(id -u) != 0 ]]; then
    zenity --error --text "root access required. Use: sudo rm-kernels"
    exit 99
fi

OLDIFS="$IFS"
IFS="|"
choices=()

current_version=$(uname -r)

for f in /boot/vmlinuz*
do
    if [[ $f == *"$current_version"* ]]; then continue; fi # skip current version
    [[ $f =~ vmlinuz-(.*) ]]
    v=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}        # example: 4.9.21-040921-generic
    v_main="${v%-*}"            # example: 4.9.21-040921

    # Kernel size in /boot/*4.9.21-040921-generic*
    s=$(du -ch /boot/*-$v* | awk '/total/{print $1}')

    if [[ $# -ne 0 ]] ; then    # Was a parameter passed?
        if [[ -d "/usr/src/linux-headers-"$v_main ]] ; then
             # Kernel headers size in /usr/src/*4.9.21-040921*
             s2=$(du -ch --max-depth=1 /usr/src/*-$v_main* | awk '/total/{print $1}')
        else
             s2="0M"            # Linux Headers are not installed
        fi
        # Kernel image size in /lib/modules/4.9.21-040921-generic*
        s3=$(du -ch --max-depth=1 /lib/modules/$v* | awk '/total/{print $1}')
    else
        # Estimate sizof of optional headers at 125MB and size of image at 220MB
        if [[ -d "/usr/src/linux-headers-"$v_main ]] ; then
             s2="125M"
        else
             s2="0M"            # Linux Headers are not installed
        fi
        s3="220M"
    fi

    # Strip out "M" provided by human readable option of du and add 3 sizes together
    s=$(( ${s//[^0-9]*} + ${s2//[^0-9]*} + ${s3//[^0-9]*} ))
    t=$(( t + s ))
    s=$s" MB"
    d=$(date --date $(stat -c %y $f) '+%b %d %Y') # Last modified date for display
    choices=("${choices[@]}" false "$v" "$d" "$s")
done

# adjust width & height below for your screen 640x480 default for 1920x1080 HD screen
# also adjust font="14" below if blue text is too small or too large

choices=(`zenity \
        --title "rm-kernels - Total: $t MB excluding: $current_version" \
        --list \
        --separator="$IFS" \
        --checklist --multiple \
        --text '<span foreground="blue" font="14">Check box next to kernel(s) to remove</span>' \
        --width=640 \
        --height=480 \
        --column "Select" \
        --column "Kernel Version Number" \
        --column "Modified Date" \
        --column " Size " \
        "${choices[@]}"`)
IFS="$OLDIFS"

i=0
list=""
for choice in "${choices[@]}" ; do
    if [ "$i" -gt 0 ]; then list="$list- "; fi # append "-" from last loop
    ((i++))

    short_choice=$(echo $choice | cut -f1-2 -d"-")
    header_count=$(find /usr/src/linux-headers-$short_choice* -maxdepth 0 -type d | wc -l)

    # If -lowlatency and -generic are purged at same time the _all header directory
    # remains on disk for specific version with no -generic or -lowlatency below.
    if [[ $header_count -lt 3 ]]; then
        # Remove all w.x.y-zzz headers
        list="$list""linux-image-$choice- linux-headers-$short_choice"
    else
        # Remove w.x.y-zzz-flavour header only, ie -generic or -lowlatency
        list="$list""linux-image-$choice- linux-headers-$choice" 
    fi

done

if [ "$i" -gt 0 ] ; then
     apt-get purge $list
fi
```

**NOTE:** You need sudo permission to create the file so use:

```bsh
gksu gedit /usr/local/bin/rm-kernels
```

To make file executable use:

```bsh
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/rm-kernels
```

---

## Server Version

`rm-kernels-server` is the server version to selectively delete kernels all at once. Instead of a GUI (graphical) dialog box a text-based dialog box is used to select kernels to purge.

- Before running the script you need to install the **dialog function** using:

  `sudo apt install dialog`

Dialog is in the default Ubuntu Desktop installation but not in Ubuntu Server.

### Sample screen

[image: rm-kernels-server 1]

### `rm-kernels-server` bash code

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# NAME: rm-kernels-server
# PATH: /usr/local/bin
# DESC: Provide dialog checklist of kernels to remove
#       Non-GUI, text based interface for server distro's.

# DATE: Mar 10, 2017. Modified Jul 28, 2017.

# NOTE: Will not delete current kernel.

#       With 10 kernels on an SSD, empty cache from sudo prompt (#) using:
#       # free && sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches && free
#       First time for `du` 34 seconds.
#       Second time for `du` 1 second.

# PARM: If any parm 1 passed use REAL kernel size, else use estimated size.
#       By default `du` is not used and estimated size is displayed.

# Must be running as sudo
if [[ $(id -u) != 0 ]]; then
    echo "root access required. Use: sudo rm-kernels-server"
    exit 99
fi

# Must have the dialog package. On Servers, not installed by default
command -v dialog >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo >&2 "dialog package required but it is not installed.  Aborting."; exit 99; }

OLDIFS="$IFS"
IFS="|"
item_list=() # Deviate from rm-kernels here.

current_version=$(uname -r)
i=0
for f in /boot/vmlinuz*
do
    if [[ $f == *"$current_version"* ]]; then continue; fi # skip current version
    [[ $f =~ vmlinuz-(.*) ]]
    ((i++)) # Item List
    v=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}        # example: 4.9.21-040921-generic
    v_main="${v%-*}"            # example: 4.9.21-040921

    # Kernel size in /boot/*4.9.21-040921-generic*
    s=$(du -ch /boot/*-$v* | awk '/total/{print $1}')

    if [[ $# -ne 0 ]] ; then    # Was a parameter passed?
        if [[ -d "/usr/src/linux-headers-"$v_main ]] ; then
             # Kernel headers size in /usr/src/*4.9.21-040921*
             s2=$(du -ch --max-depth=1 /usr/src/*-$v_main* | awk '/total/{print $1}')
        else
             s2="0M"            # Linux Headers are not installed
        fi
        # Kernel image size in /lib/modules/4.9.21-040921-generic*
        s3=$(du -ch --max-depth=1 /lib/modules/$v* | awk '/total/{print $1}')
    else
        # Estimate sizof of optional headers at 125MB and size of image at 220MB
        if [[ -d "/usr/src/linux-headers-"$v_main ]] ; then
             s2="125M"
        else
             s2="0M"            # Linux Headers are not installed
        fi
        s3="220M"
    fi

    # Strip out "M" provided by human readable option of du and add 3 sizes together
    s=$(( ${s//[^0-9]*} + ${s2//[^0-9]*} + ${s3//[^0-9]*} ))
    t=$(( t + s ))
    s=$s" MB"
    d=$(date --date $(stat -c %y $f) '+%b %d %Y') # Last modified date for display
    item_list=("${item_list[@]}" "$i" "$v ! $d ! $s" off)
done

cmd=(dialog --backtitle "rm-kernels-server - Total: $t MB excluding: $current_version" \
    --title "Use space bar to toggle kernel(s) to remove" \
    --column-separator "!" \
    --separate-output \
    --ascii-lines \
    --checklist "         Kernel Version --------- Modified Date  Size" 20 60 15)

selections=$("${cmd[@]}" "${item_list[@]}" 2>&1 >/dev/tty)

IFS=$OLDIFS

if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
    echo cancel selected
    exit 1
fi

i=0
choices=()

for select in $selections ; do
    ((i++))
    j=$(( 1 + ($select - 1) * 3 ))
    choices[i]=$(echo ${item_list[j]} | cut -f1 -d"!")
done

i=0
list=""
for choice in "${choices[@]}" ; do
    if [ "$i" -gt 0 ]; then list="$list- "; fi # append "-" from last loop
    ((i++))

    short_choice=$(echo $choice | cut -f1-2 -d"-")
    header_count=$(find /usr/src/linux-headers-$short_choice* -maxdepth 0 -type d | wc -l)

    # If -lowlatency and -generic are purged at same time the _all header directory
    # remains on disk for specific version with no -generic or -lowlatency below.
    if [[ $header_count -lt 3 ]]; then
        # Remove all w.x.y-zzz headers
        list="$list""linux-image-$choice- linux-headers-$short_choice"
    else
        # Remove w.x.y-zzz-flavour header only, ie -generic or -lowlatency
        list="$list""linux-image-$choice- linux-headers-$choice" 
    fi

done

if [ "$i" -gt 0 ] ; then
    apt-get purge $list
fi
```

**NOTE:** In the call to `dialog` the directive `--ascii-lines` is passed to replace line-draw extended character set (which `ssh` doesn't like) with "+-----+" for drawing boxes. If you do not like this appearance you can use the `--no-lines` directive for no box at all.

---

### July 28, 2017 Updates

The calculated size of each kernel was taken from `/boot/*kernel_version*` which were 5 files totaling ~50 MB. The formula has changed to include the files in `/usr/src/*kernel_version*` and `/lib/modules/*kernel_version*`. The calculated size for each kernel is now ~400 MB. The above code for `rm-kernels` and `rm-kernels-server` has been updated. However, the sample screens above do not reflect these changes yet.

The default is to estimate the size of files for linux-headers at 125 MB and linux-image at 220 MB because `du` can be painfully slow unless files are in cache. To get the real size using `du` pass any parameter to the script.

The total of all kernel sizes (excluding the current running version which cannot be removed) is now show in the title bar.

The dialog box used to display each Kernel's **Last Access Date**. This date can get mass overwritten for all kernels during backup or similar operations. The dialog box now shows the **Modified Date** instead.

Answer (score 4):

I have a script for this that does not need very fancy string parsing.

Remove headers and images except the current one to release space

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge 'linux-headers-[0-9].*' linux-headers-$(uname -r)+ linux-headers-$(uname -r | cut -d- -f1,2)+ 'linux-image-[0-9].*' linux-image-$(uname -r)+
```

Comment: Worked better than butter on toast!

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to get rid of almost all obsolete packages, packages no longer in any package list, along with obsolete kernels is to do one of the following:

```
dpkg --purge $(aptitude search ?obsolete)
```

However, this will miss packages that are still recommended by other packages, and the -R/--without-recommends argument does not resolve this problem.

dselect after switching sort mode with 'o' will show all obsolete packages including the ones aptitude misses, but some people don't like using it.

Comment: The given command does not purge old kernels nor affect grub menu in my experience.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer using `sed` to remove older kernels permanently has some flaws, if someone has not rebooted the computer after upgrading kernel the command will remove the newer kernel too.

Here is an alternate solution that will consider all situations to remove actual older kernels only:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
kernels=( $(grep -Po "^linux-image-[^-]+-[^-]+-generic\b" < <(dpkg --get-selections)) )
cur_rel=$(grep -Po ".*(?=-[a-z]*$)" < <(uname -r))

for kernel in "${kernels[@]}"; do
    ker_rel=$(grep -Po "[0-9].*(?=-[a-z]*)" <<< "$kernel")
    dpkg --compare-versions "$ker_rel" gt "$cur_rel" && echo "Please Restart your computer first" && break
    dpkg --compare-versions "$ker_rel" lt "$cur_rel" && sudo apt-get remove "$kernel"
done
```

If you have any version that is newer than the current one this will give you a warning to restart you computer first. Also note that the older kernels are preserved due to a good reason which is if you somehow mess up your current kernel making your system unstable then you should be able to boot into any older kernel.

Comment: This will not remove lowlatency kernels or kernels of any other flavor than generic.

Comment: I suppose you refer to [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/65104/21005) `sed` solutions.

Comment: @jarno : How about replacing `grep -Po "^linux-image-[^-]+-[^-]+-generic\b"` with `grep -Eo "^linux-(image|headers|tools)-[^-]+-[^-]+(|-generic)\s" | sed -e "s/\s//g"` and `grep -Po ".*(?=-[a-z]*$)"` with `grep -Eo "^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+-[0-9]+"` and `grep -Po "[0-9].*(?=-[a-z]*)"` with `grep -Eo "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+-[0-9]+"`?

Comment: @Sadi, wel,l that would not find lowlatency kernels either.

Comment: @jarno : Thanks, the first replacement above should be like this then:  `grep -Eo "^linux-(image|headers|tools)-[^-]+-[^-]+(|-generic|-lowlatency)\s" | sed -e "s/\s//g"`

Comment: Thanks. Other methods didn't work for me. Yours did the job.

Answer (score 2):

[ailurus](http://code.google.com/p/ailurus/) has the feature of removing old kernels as well as unused configurations. I personally remove it manually from synaptic. You can install ailurus from [getdeb](http://getdeb.net) as well as [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ailurus/+archive/ppa)

Comment: "Ailurus is a tool for backup a name list of installed software. ... In the past Ailurus has many function. Now it has only one function. Because I think one really useful function is better than dozens of less useful function."

Answer (score 2):

Based on a previous answer by David Kemp, the following script will purge all headers and images except for the **last 2** versions.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# This script assumes that the installed linux-image and linux-headers packages
# share the same versions (i.e. if a linux-image version number is installed,
# the corresponding linux-headers package will also be installed, and vice
# versa.)

SECONDTOLASTVER=$(dpkg --list | grep linux-image | awk '{ print $2 }' | sort -r -n | sed '/^[^0-9]\+$/d' | sed 's/^.*-\([0-9\.]\+-[0-9]\+\).*/\1/' | uniq | sed -n 2p)

# get a list of package names matching the argument passed to the function, and
# return only those package names which should be removed
get_pkgs_to_remove_matching () {
    if [ -n "$SECONDTOLASTVER" ]; then
        echo $(dpkg --list | grep $1 | awk '{ print $2 }' | sort | sed -n '/'"$SECONDTOLASTVER"'/q;p')
    fi
}

echo $(get_pkgs_to_remove_matching linux-image) $(get_pkgs_to_remove_matching linux-headers) | xargs sudo apt-get purge
```

(use `apt-get -y` to remove without question)

Comment: Any reason why this was downvoted?  Did it not work for someone? When copying/pasting make sure you aren't wrapping long-lines when you paste.  I have had no problems with it working.

Comment: Newest kernel release in my machine is 3.13.0-43-lowlatency. This script would purge linux-headers-3.13.0-43-lowlatency.

Comment: @jarno how did you determine that?  to try it out without actually doing anything, add a "-s" flag to the apt-get command (or just remove the `| xargs sudo apt-get -y purge` altogether).  If it prints out 3.13.0-43-lowlatency, then perhaps you have some later versions than that installed on your system.

Comment: I tried simulation. No, but I had some earlier kernel version removed, but not purged, and respective header packages purged.

Comment: Anyway, I have been developing a script based on the idea of Sankalp's answer.

Comment: I published it here as a separate answer: [link](http://askubuntu.com/a/571360/21005)

Answer (score 2):

You can use ukuu - it's all GUI - to update and delete old Kernels. Works for me!

Just remember leave the last 2 installed and obviously the 'running' kernel.

You can also set ukuu to only show mainline releases, even RC kernels, hide point releases.

[image: ukuu]

You can find ukuu in Synaptic, or instructions are here:

[OMG!Ubuntu ukuu install instructions](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/02/ukuu-easy-way-to-install-mainline-kernel-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Next time, when removing old kernels open a Terminal and use this command:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove linux-headers-2.6.38-10-generic
```

You can use Synaptic to get the exact name of the kernel that you intend to delete. Just open Synaptic and search for "linux-headers" and then select which kernel entry you want to remove. The relevant entry will be tagged with "-generic" at the end.

To clear out any unused (left over) dependencies throughout the system use this command by itself:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: dependencies are removed but I still have these files in /boot folder.

Comment: I think you should use `--purge` option and purge the respective linux-image packages as well as linux-headers packages.

Answer (score 1):

here is a rough outline of what I did, careful as I am no expert in linux, be sure you know what you are doing and have backed up any files you are modifying.

```
gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

then find the entries you want to keep, we will highlight and copy them

```
cd /etc/grub.d
ls
```

you'll see a list of files like 10_linux and 30_os-prober

```
sudo chmod -x 10_linux
```

this will stop form auto adding all the linux entries into the grub boot menu.

```
gksudo gedit 40_custom
```

open the custom boot menu file, then go back to grub.cfg (which should still be open in gedit), and copy the entries you want to keep... such as

```
menuentry "My Default Karmic" {
  set root=(hd0,1)
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set cb201140-52f8-4449-9a95-749b27b58ce8
  linux /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.31-11-generic root=UUID=cb201140-52f8-4449-9a95-749b27b58ce8 ro quiet splash
  initrd /boot/initrd.img-2.6.31-11-generic
}
```

paste them into `40_custom`, and then save it.

```
sudo chmod 755 40_custom
```

makes it executable, then finally we update grub which will change the grub.cfg file:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now, BEWARE, if you update your kernel or OS, your boot menu probably will not update... you'll have to do that manually. But doing this procedure will let you customize the boot menu a bit more, such as remove the kernel version and just put the ubuntu name... i.e. Ubuntu Lucid 10.04, etc...

Hope someone finds this helpful, as it took me a while to figure out... didn't see this solution anywhere...

Comment: This answer seems like overkill. It's better to just remove old kernels.

Comment: I had read that extra kernels may be useful in the event of recovery situations. Also, this is a simple way to edit the text of the boot entry. So rather than saying "Ubuntu, Linux kernel x.x.xx-yy --text1 -text2 -t3 -t4 --t5 etc etc etc" (where the --text entries just denote some options/parameters I don't understand) you can change it to "Ubuntu xx.yy" although I had a "{" bracket I couldn't get rid of.

Comment: I keep the immediate previous kernel around until I've verified the the most current kernel works properly. If it works, it isn't going to stop working. So, after I've verified the most recent kernel (after a week or so), I have no reason to keep the old kernel around. If it doesn't work, then I have the latest known-good kernel to fall back to. Actually, I'm currently running an old kernel due to a showstopper bug in the current kernels. But that doesn't change my overall policy. You only need one known good kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Install the **synaptic package manager** and go down to the filters tab (I think filters, if not try all 5) and select "local".  This will show you orphaned packages on your system, such as the kernels.  After you uninstall them, run `update-grub`.  That command updates the list of boot options for grub.

If this fails, you can always try `apt-get remove linux-image-version-generic`.

Comment: In Synaptic you can filter on 'Components' -> 'Kernel and modules', which include all the kernels. And sort by the first column: 'S' (Status), so you get all the installed kernels on-top.

Indeed `update-grub` is advised.

Answer (score 1):

To have a bit more control over which versions to keep, explicitly select the ones you want to remove. For instance if you want to remove kernel versions 3.2.0.[49-53], use a simple `for` loop:

```
for k in 49 51 52 53 ; do aptitude remove --purge linux-image-3.2.0-${k}-generic ; done
```

Adjust the list of kernel versions to fit.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.
Run it as root.

Save this script as, say *./keep-n-kernels.sh*

Pass, as a command line argument, the number of most recent kernels you want to preserve.

```
    
#!/bin/bash

# pass n as a command line argument, and it will find all the installed
# kernels and keep only the n most recent ones => uninstall all older ones

# dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d'
# this command gives the list of all packages EXCEPT for the latest kernel.
# source : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/RemoveOldKernels

n=$1

# find the installed kernel versions :
# dpkg-query -W -f='${Version}\n' 'linux-image-*' | grep . | sort -n
# gives version numbers, one in each line
# dpkg-query -W -f='${Version}\n' 'linux-image-*' | grep . | sed 's/\...$//g' | grep -v '\...$'| sort -u
# gives only the ones that appear in linux-image

# suffix, e.g. -generic-pae
# the kind of kernel you boot into
suffix=$(uname -r | sed 's:^[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]\-[0-9]\{2\}::g')

command="apt-get purge "

for version in $(dpkg-query -W -f='${Version}\n' 'linux-image-*' | grep . | sed 's/\...$//g' | grep -v '\...$'| sort -u | head -n -${n})
do
    command=${command}"^linux-image-${version}${suffix} "
done

$command
```

Sample usage :

```
# ./keep-n-kernels.sh 4 # launch the apt-get command to remove all but the 4 most recent kernels
```

If you want [AND AT YOUR OWN RISK], you can add a -y (or a force flag) to the apt-get command and make it non-interactive.

Comment: It removes all kernels, if you run ./keep-n-kernels.sh 0. Detecting suffix string does not work; I think suffix=$(uname -r | sed -r 's/^[0-9.]*(-[0-9.]+)*//') or suffix=$(uname -r | egrep --only-matching -- '-[[:alpha:]-]+$') would do.

Comment: But I think the idea is nice. I have been working on improving the script and maybe I'll post it here sometime, when I think it is ready enough.

Comment: Do please share, @jarno . Glad to know the idea seems useful.

Comment: Ok, there it is: [link](http://askubuntu.com/a/571360/21005)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a KDE desktop, and the easiest option I found was using the kde-config-grub2 application as suggested here: https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?58075-remove-old-linux-versions (which I already had installed for setting background image, default boot option, and the like). Next to the drop-down box where you can choose the default entry, there is a "Remove Old Entries" button. Clicking this button presents you with a list of all installed kernels and you can select which ones to remove. When you apply the changes it will use dpkg to actually remove them from the system as well as the GRUB menu.

Answer (score 1):

Just to chime in, you can also issue

`apt-get remove linux-{image,headers}-x.y.z-{1,2,...,n}`

as root, and the job will be done.

Answer (score 0):

The following string of commands will purge any installed linux kernels except the currently running one (grep -v `uname -r`) and the lastest available kernel (dpkg -l | .... | tail -1):

```
dpkg -l | grep -E linux-image-.*-generic | cut -d ' ' -f3 | grep -v `dpkg -l | grep -E linux-image-.*-generic | cut -d ' ' -f3 | tail -1` | grep -v `uname -r` | xargs apt-get -y purge
```

I use this to keep desktop's boot volumes relatively clean, but in a server situation you'd probably want to expand the logic and write some additional scripting to maintain a list of the last X kernels the server has booted.

Something like a startup script that does:

```
uname -r >> /root/bootedkernels
cat /root/bootedkernels | sort -u | tail -3 > /root/bootedkernels # Keep the last 3 booted kernels
```

and then use:

```
dpkg -l | grep -E linux-image-.*-generic | cut -d ' ' -f3 | grep -vf /root/bootedkernels | grep -v `dpkg -l | grep -E linux-image-.*-generic | cut -d ' ' -f3 | tail -1` | grep -v `uname -r` | xargs apt-get -y purge
```

Comment: Simpler form would be `sudo apt-get purge $(dpkg-query -W -f'${Package}\n' 'linux-image-[0-9]*' | head -n -1 | grep -v $(uname -r))`, but even that raises questions: Can you rely on that dpkg lists newest kernel last? Can you rely on matching the current version as such regular expression? A dot in version string matches any character.  What if the package name has one more character in version number than the current version? To be strict, you had better use `uname -r  | sed -r -e 's/\./\\./g' -e 's/.*/-&($|-)/'` as the regular expression to match in the last grep command.

Comment: Besides, the script does not purge any linux-header packages or other related packages.

Comment: DO NOT USE THIS! It will remove old kernels without question. I tried without `-y` but then the command breaks before executing

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ansible to control the machines, this playbook might be helpful.

```
---
 - hosts: all
   become: yes
   tasks:
    - name: "Run apt-get autoremove"
      apt: 
        name: linux-image-generic
        autoremove: yes
        state: present 
        update_cache: yes
        cache_valid_time: 3600
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather use `apt`, the cli frontend for humans, than `apt-get` to purge old kernel images:

```
$ sudo apt autoremove --purge
...
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-51* linux-headers-4.4.0-51-generic* linux-image-4.4.0-51-generic* linux-image-extra-4.4.0-51-generic*
```

Comment: What's the difference here between apt and apt-get?  (Note, apt is not available on a plain 12.04 installation.)

Comment: @mwfearnley For basic difference, see [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/445384/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-and-apt-get) When I was researching this, `apt-get` did not purge the old kernels for me. `apt` did, yet I also may have used them differently.

Answer (score 0):

I use `unattended-upgrades` so I really liked [Qwerty's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/104370/133393) that configures it to uninstall old kernel packages automatically.

However there was one issue: after a new kernel is installed, this process would uninstall the package for the currently running kernel!

That doesn't break the OS entirely. In fact I rarely noticed it had happened, until I needed to hot-load a module (e.g. by plugging in a USB device) and then the module could not be found.

As a solution to this, I created a script to generate a virtual package `currently-installed-kernel` which effectively pins the current kernel package until the next boot.

The script is called `pin-current-kernel-with-package.sh`.  Here is the [latest version](https://github.com/joeytwiddle/jsh/blob/master/code/shellscript/apt/pin-current-kernel-with-package.sh) (probably) and the [first version](https://github.com/joeytwiddle/jsh/blob/75f59ff8d434b37b7be870fe3ad272e771105023/code/shellscript/apt/pin-current-kernel-with-package.sh) (definitely).

Just save that script somewhere, and [add it to your bootup process](https://askubuntu.com/a/1199/133393).  For example, save it in `/usr/local/bin/pin-current-kernel-with-package.sh` and then edit `/etc/rc.local` and add the following line:

```
bash /usr/local/bin/pin-current-kernel-with-package.sh
```

Now your running kernel package will never be uninstalled!

Comment: More recent versions of `unattended-upgrades` might be more intelligent about this now, so you might not need this script. [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/1217882/133393)

Answer (score 0):

I give two safer variations of the methods in other answers: one using *synaptic manager* and the other using *terminal*.

With these variations you only remove packages that the system identifies as removable. There is no risk you remove linux kernels that are currently used—as it happened to me some weeks ago ;-(

### Using Synaptic Manager

Instead of searching `linux-image` over *all* installed packages, select the **autoremovable** packages (See red ellipse in the picture below). Now from this list remove the *linux-image* you want.

[image]

### Using terminal

Similarly, if you are removing kernels on terminal, show only the **autoremovable** kernels by running

```
 sudo apt-get -s autoremove | grep linux-image
```

And then remove whichever kernel `linux-image-x.x.x-x-generic` you want to remove from the given list by running

```
 sudo apt-get purge linux-image-x.x.x-x-generic
```

Answer (score 0):

To **remove** the kernels that were automatically installed via regular system updates, open terminal and run:

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge
```

To know your current kernel release run `uname -r` and also u can run `uname --help` to read more about all **uname** commands

You can also run `df -h` to show you file system drivers, similarly you can run `df --help` for more.

To enable automatic removing of old kernels:
Edit the config file using **gksu**

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades
```

When the file opens, uncomment the following line and change the value to **true**:

//Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Dependencies "**false**";

If you need to install **gksu**, you can run `sudo apt install gksu`

To clear old packages we can use `sudo apt-get clean`

For More, visit http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/05/remove-old-kernels-ubuntu-16-04/

Answer (score 0):

As [@jarno](https://askubuntu.com/users/21005/jarno) and [@earcam](https://askubuntu.com/users/21832/earcam) mentioned in their comments on the question, you first want to ensure all your linux kernel packages are marked as having been autoinstalled:

```
sudo apt-mark auto '^linux-.*-4\.12\.0-12(-generic)?$'
```

Then the normal `apt-get autoremove` command should work.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```

Read the [docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

**Read all the answer before executing the commands.**

How I did it :

First get the kernal you are using
uname -r

List the kernels, and note down the kernel that is just **older** (version  5.15.0-35 **when you run the  5.15.0-36** - see the **35 and 36** at the end?) and another one:  5.14.0-46 (the latest of the 5.14 serie). That way, **you want to keep two versions to revert to if needed).**

(as a reminder : grep -v : if you want to find something which doesn’t match a given pattern, grep allows doing just that with -v flag)

```
 dpkg --list | egrep -i 'linux-image|linux-headers'
```

Remove the kernel unwanted. Note that the

```
 sudo apt-get --purge remove $(dpkg --list | egrep -i 'linux-image|linux-headers' | awk '/ii/{ print $2}' | grep -v `uname -r` | grep -v 5.15.0-35 | grep -v 5.14.0-46 )
```

the following might not be necessary, but it freed up space for me too - even if it should be the same than the set of command before

```
 dpkg -S "linux-image" 
 sudo apt-get --purge remove $(dpkg -S "linux-image" | cut -f'1' -d':' | grep -v 5.11 | grep -v 5.15.0-35 | grep -v 5.14.0-46 )
```

At the end, do :

```
 sudo apt autoremove
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this `remove_kernel` script for removing old versions of kernel:

```shell
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ -z "${1}" ]; then
  echo 'Choose one of kernels as command line parameter:'
  ls -l /boot | grep initrd | grep '^-r' | awk -F'-' '{print$8"-"$9}'
  exit 1
else
  KRNL="${1}"
fi

echo 'These files will be deleted:'
echo '------'
dpkg --list | egrep -i "$KRNL" | awk '{print$2}'
echo '------'
echo "  Version to remove: ${KRNL}"
echo "  Current version: $(uname -r | awk -F'-' '{print$1"-"$2}')"
echo '------'
printf 'Do you want to proceed [enter y to continue]: '
read iamagree

if [ "${iamagree}x" == "yx" ]; then
  sudo apt-get -y --purge remove $(dpkg --list | egrep -i "$KRNL" | awk '{print$2}' | xargs)
else
  echo "cancelled"
fi
```

Usage:

```
$ remove_kernel
Choose one of kernels as command line parameter:
5.19.0-35
5.19.0-38
```

```
$ remove_kernel 5.19.0-35
These files will be deleted:
------
linux-headers-5.19.0-35-generic
linux-hwe-5.19-headers-5.19.0-35
linux-image-5.19.0-35-generic
linux-modules-5.19.0-35-generic
linux-modules-extra-5.19.0-35-generic
------
  Version to remove: 5.19.0-35
  Current version: 5.19.0-38
------
Do you want to proceed [enter y to continue]: y
...
```

Checked with `Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS`

Answer (score -2):

Here's the script I use to keep 2 kernel packages installed (i.e. the current one and the previous one). It also removes the initrd-VERSION-generic.old-dkms files left around by DKMS, which can fill-up a small boot partition.

The script:

```
echo "**Removing -generic.old-dkms files from /boot**" && rm -f /boot/*-generic.old-dkms # if using DKMS it creates initrd-VERSION-generic.old-dkms in /boot and doesn't clean them up, meaning after a few kernel upgrades /boot can become full
OLDKERNEL=$(ls -tr /boot/vmlinuz-* | head -n -2 | cut -d- -f2- | awk '{print "linux-image-" $0}')
OLDHEADERS=$(ls -tr /boot/vmlinuz-* | head -n -2 | cut -d- -f2- | sed 's/-generic//g' | awk '{print "linux-headers-" $0}')
OLDHEADERS=${OLDHEADERS//-pae/} # remove -pae string as linux-header packages don't have it in their names
if [ -n "$OLDKERNEL" -o -n "$OLDHEADERS" ]; then
apt-get -q remove --purge $OLDKERNEL $OLDHEADERS
echo "**Finished removing old kernels**"
else
echo "**No old kernels found**"
fi
```